# How to change the default number of print copies in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way that I can change the default number of copies from 1 to 2 in chrome printing options?

Currently, everytime I print I have to manually change the number of copies to 2.

Comment: Not possible. Chrome uses the Windows Print Dialog.

Comment: If using Windows, Edge manages Printers.   I use this.